# Add Node Content Before A view?

Tags: views

What's the best approach at adding a node above a view. Right now i'm using the views html (before) to add 3 links to pdf's and some text.

I'm not interested in using panels; primarily, because the content has to appear below the view header.

Would it be best to add each file as nodes and join the view with a relationship?

Comment: how does the node you want to insert after the view header relate to the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the page view to a block view and add the block to the nodes in the content region.

Answer (score 3):

As NMC said, views attachment is probably the easiest solution, to attached a view to your node.

You asked to display a node above a view.   Depending on your arguments of your view, the easiest way is to use Attaching Display.

In your view:

- Create a new display called Attachment.
- Change Attachment Settings -> Position: Before.
- Change Attachment Settings -> Attached To:  to the view you want.
- (Optional) Override and change the Style settings -> Row Style: from Fields to Node (maybe also have to override Style settings -> Style to unformatted before).

[image: Views Attachment Display]

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted. I would never have thought of this display type. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the information you want to insert before the view is in a node, you can add a Views Attachment to your Page View so that the attachment View is rendered not on top of the Page View but within, below the Page View header.